# how to define a class using c++

Tags: c++, class

I need to define a class to hold stock data in c++. At minimum it needs a method for "meanvalue", a method for "vairance", and properties for "trading volume" and other historical data.

Comment: Walk us through the ways you think you should define it.  If you hit any technical snags, let us know!

Comment: "some historical data" - lie what, closing prices for the last 5 trading days, or the last year, or all trades ever?

Comment: Stick the stock on the stack.

Comment: Sounds like the kind of question a s/e from the UBS algorithmic trading team would ask...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a start:

```
class Stock
{
public:
    Stock();
    ~Stock();

    int MeanValue();
    int Variance();

private:
    int mMeanValue;
    int mVariance;
};
```

I'll leave the implementation of the methods in this class up to you.

Comment: Missing that final semi.

Comment: And a container for historical data.

Comment: @Duck - And I quote: Here's a *start* :-)

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat - Just busting you.  You put more into it than I would have.

Comment: ints for mean values?  You can't be serious...

Comment: @tim - Yes, I only put in a fraction more thought into my answer than the poster did for the original question!

Comment: Stock also should have instrument ID and at least one symbol name I think. But that should be derived from Instrument class, which also would be a base for Option, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to have a name property, and perhaps an exchange property, method to handle updates to specific things like volume, quotes, trade prices, etc.  You can do this with key/value pairs or define methods for each.

For things like variance and history, you will have to have methods that are triggered by the updates so you can change the calculated values.

You really should consider showing us what you have, then we'll be more likely to help...